# jekyll liquid directives not processed in github-pages main index.html; what am I missing?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Newbie question.  I'm trying to get started with github-pages and Jekyll, working my way through the docs.  I got to this: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#displaying-an-index-of-posts and I thought I'd put the Liquid directives directly into my main **index.html**, but they don't get processed.  Instead, they just come out verbatim:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

(Obviously, the HTML doesn't come out verbatim, but the Liquid stuff does.)

**My directory structure** (Created with the github automatic page generator):

```
./   Gemfile       .git/       images/     javascripts/  _posts/  stylesheets/
../  Gemfile.lock  .gitignore  index.html  params.json   _site/
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
versions = JSON.parse(open('https://pages.github.com/versions.json').read)

gem 'github-pages', versions['github-pages']
```

I've run `bundle install` and `bundle update`.  I do have a post.

`bundle exec jekyll serve` serves everything up fine, except for this error/warning:

```
Configuration file: none
```

What am I missing?

(Thanks.)

Comment: Does your `index.html` have a [front matter section](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)?

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you, Matt & Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so... turns out all you need is to put "front matter" in your index.html to trigger its processing by Jekyll (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).  The minimal front matter is two lines of three dashes, which works for me.

On to the next hurdle!